# Correct type of shower handle to use for valve that sticks out too far?

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I'm attempting to install a shower handle on an unfinished build. The problem I'm facing is the handle plate does not fit over the white pipe that is sticking out of the wall. Should that white portion be sticking out past the tile?

The handle I bought fits right over the valve, but it doesn't fit over the white pipe. Did I just buy the wrong type of handle, or is there some kind of plate adapter to work around this problem?

[image]

Edit: Here's a pic of the plate over the valve. This was the reason I made the assumption that the valve stuck out too far. I like the approach of taking the pic to a plumbing store to make sure I end up with the right type of handle.

[image]

Comment: add a pic of the handle put on the valve.  Also you have the escutcheon plate?  That typically covers the white portion of the valve body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are calling a white pipe is likely the body of the mixing valve. The installation as it is now looks carefully done: a nice circular hole, and a schluter kerdi seal around the hole (the orange plastic ring inside the hole). I wouldn't jump to the conclusion that it sticks out to much. You probably just bought the wrong brand of handle.

You're best bet is to take this photo to a plumbing supplier and hope the can identify what brand of mixing valve you have.  Then you can order a handle and escutcheon (the cover plate) that fit your valve properly. I don't recognize the brand myself, I can only tell you it doesn't look like a Moen valve.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot cut the pipe back I would make a spacer. I would make it a couple of inches larger than the cover plate the same shape (if round make the spacer round) by making the spacer larger and the same shape it will look like it was planned for decorative reason instead of a mistake. If you need multiple layers  make each one larger by a similar amount and it should look nice in the end. Just make sure to seal it well.